# .net MAUI, android System.InvalidOperationException: 'Native View not set' on navigation

Tags: c#, android, maui

Can't find source of evil, have two pages, added as Singleton service, when i navigate to the second page for a first time everything great, when i navigate second time i get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Native View not set'
```

```
MAUI version 6.0.300-rc.2.5513+sha.8a017cf73-azdo.6048189
```

Emulator Android11 API 30

Tested on Desktop everything seems ok...

MauiProgram.cs

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ShellViewModel>();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppShell>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<SettingsPage>();



        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

App.xaml - default to new project
App.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppShell();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(SettingsPage), typeof(SettingsPage));
    }
}
```

AppShell.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiAppTest.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiAppTest"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiAppTest.ViewModels"
    x:DataType="vm:ShellViewModel"
    
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
    <Shell.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Command="{Binding GoToSettings}" Text="Settings"/>
    </Shell.ToolbarItems>
    <ShellContent
        Title="Hello, World!"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>
```

AppShell.cs

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new ShellViewModel();
    }
}
```

ShellViewModel.cs

```
    public class ShellViewModel: ObservableObject
    {
        public AsyncRelayCommand GoToSettings { get; private set; }

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            GoToSettings = new AsyncRelayCommand(async () => await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("SettingsPage"));
        }
    }
```

MainPage and SettingsPage just two default blank pages

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAppTest.MainPage"
             Title="MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAppTest.SettingsPage"
             Title="SettingsPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: As a test, what happens if instead of `AddSingleton` you use `AddTransient`: `builder.Services.AddTransient<SettingsPage>();`? (Testing whether Maui is not correctly using the singleton class.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer I actually found what causing it: await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("SettingsPage")); should be await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("SettingsPage", false));

Comment: Seems some android specific crap, gonna post issue on their git

Comment: Sounds similar to the issue I reported. However, disabling the animation from `GoToAsync` didn't help me. [VirtualView cannot be null here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12219)